# Does change detection in angular2 always start in root component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Consider the following component tree structure in `Angular2`

```
     A
  B     C
D  E   F  G
```

If `G` emits an event via click to `C` and `C` does not further that event

`html`

```
<div (click)="update($event)"></div>
```

`component`

```
@Output() myOutputName = new EventEmitter();

update(event) {
    this.myOutputName.emit('some vlaue'); 
}
```

Does the Change detection runs in all nodes starting from `A` or does change detection start on `C` and effect only `F` and `G` ?

Answer (score 2):

> **YES, CHANGE DETECTION ALWAYS STARTS FROM ROOT COMPONENT**

**slide** - 
http://pascalprecht.github.io/slides/angular-2-change-detection-explained/#/54

> Data always flows from top to bottom, is because change detection is also
>   always performed from top to bottom for every single component, every
>   single time, starting from the **root component**

So if ***`G`*** emits an event,
change detection will start from root component,

***`A`***                        `(change detection in A)`

***`B`      `C`***                  `(change detection in B,C)`
                                     ***`D`    `E`      `F`    `G`***           `(change detection in D,E,F,G)`

Keep in mind, there are ways to deal with change detection. 
**But Yes BY DEFAULT, change detection starts from Root**

For further reference,

**article** 
 1) http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html
2) http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2

Comment: Angular also doesn't know what changed, it only assumes that when an event handler was called that there is a chance that something changed and runs change detection on the full app starting from the root component.

Comment: Yes absolutely @Gunter.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the Change detection runs

It depends.  By default, change detection will run after every asynchronous event (well, every asynchronous event that was monkey-patched by Zone.js), starting from the top/root of the component tree and then visiting each node once, in depth-first order.  So A-B-D-E-C-F-G (not A-B-C-D-E-F-G, which would be breadth-first order).

However, if you have change detection disabled for component G (see [`detach()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html)), then change detection will not run after the click handler runs.

> Does the Change detection runs in all nodes

Again, it depends.  By default yes, every node is checked.

However, components can be detached from the change detector tree (as I just mentioned), or they can be configured to use the `OnPush` change detection strategy.  If a component uses `OnPush`, it will only be checked if gets "marked" for check, by one of the following conditions/events:

- one of its input properties changed
- the component fired an event (i.e., some event binding in its template fired an event)
- a observable fired an event and that observable is used with `| async` in the view/template
- the component was "marked" for check by a call to [`markForCheck()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html) – this could have been called in the component logic, or in some descendant logic (more about this below)

If the `OnPush` component is not "marked", that component will not be checked for changed, **nor will any of its descendants** be checked (regardless of the change detection strategy they are using).  So, if component G uses the default change detection strategy, but parent component C uses `OnPush`, if C is not marked for check, G won't be checked either.

You can manually mark an `OnPush` component using `markForCheck()`.  This method will also mark all of its ancestors up to the root component.   It must do this because change detection always starts from the root... and in order for change detection to make it back down to the "marked" component, Angular has to make sure that any other `OnPush` components up the chain/tree are also marked.  Otherwise, change detection will never make it back down to this component.

`OnPush` is often a good choice for leaf nodes/components that only use input properties (i.e., they don't get their data from services.)

---

By default, change detection always starts from the root component.  However, if you manually call [`detectChanges()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html), it will only check the current component and its descendants.

Comment: Why did React choose to trigger the change detection only from the node it originated using setState and not from the root?

Comment: Between detectChanges() and markForCheck() which one is more performant or better option? When to use which?

Comment: Use always markForCheck... detectChanges is for rare cases